# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{16x^2-9}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help with this exercise.

Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{16x^2-9}}dx$

This is why I've tried but it seems wrong.

$$\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{16x^2-9}}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{4 \cdot 1}{4 \cdot x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx$$

$$=4\int \frac{1}{4x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx$$

$$=4\left(\frac{1}{3} \sec^{-1} \frac{|4x|}{3}\right) + C$$

I've checked in multiple math solvers that gives me the answer but not the process and answer is the same but without the 4 that is in the beginning. Is there a way that I can do it without trigonometric substitution? I know that this can be done with trigonometric substitution (I've already tried it and got the answer right) but this exercise appears in a section of a book of derivatives and integrals of Inverse Trigonometric Functions which is before the chapter where all the techniques of integrations appears. So this is supposed to be done without using that knowledge. So I'm wondering how I can get the answer using a simpler way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)

Comment: Try letting $u = \sqrt{16x^2 - 9}$.

Comment: Hey! @SineoftheTime thanks! but it didn't help. That solver is using rationalizing substitution which I also know I could use but like I said that technique and trigonometric subtitution is later in the book, that I'm supposed to be able to do it without that knowledge. :-/

Comment: @Accelerator maybe my book is crazy because that technique and trigonometric subtitution appear later in my book. I shouldn't be using those techniques if the exercise appear in a section of the book that is before those techniques.

Comment: Are you really not allowed to use a $u$-substitution for this problem? What techniques are you allowed to use then?

Comment: @Accelerator yes but simple $u$-substitution, not rationalizing $u$-substitution. I already found it. $u=4x$. it blew my mind how simple the substitution was. :-S

Comment: I don't know what rationalizing a $u$-substitution means, but IMO, If the problem was written such that the reader had already learned $u$-substitution, then I don't think it's much of a stretch for the reader to think of letting $u$ equal the entire square root.

Comment: @Accelerator rationalizing substitution is what you suggested, substituting the whole radical by $u$. At least that's how my book calls it, but I'm not allowed to used that substitution because is later in the book. It hasn't been discussed yet. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: You have $dx$ and not $d(4x)$, so your last step is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "simpler way". :-S

Is using substitution with $u=4x$, so $x=\frac{u}{4}$, then $du=4dx$, so $\frac{du}{4}=dx$.

$$\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{16x^2-9}}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{\frac{u}{4} \sqrt{u^2-3^2}}\cdot\frac{du}{4}$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-3^2}}du$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}sec^{-1}\frac{|u|}{3}+C$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}sec^{-1}\frac{|4x|}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

In the last step, you're forgetting to use the chain rule:
$$\int \frac{1}{4x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx=\frac14\int \frac{4}{4x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx=\frac{1}{4}\frac 13 \sec^{-1}\frac{|4x|}{3}+c$$
Hence:
$$4\int \frac{1}{4x \sqrt{(4x)^2-3^2}}dx= \frac 13 \sec^{-1}\frac{|4x|}{3}+c$$

Comment: how chain rule is applied here. I'm sorry, not seeing it.

Comment: @bdvg2302 basically, you're forgetting to derive $4x$

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this taught in such a way that we find the derivatives of the inverse trig functions.

$\frac {d}{dx} \sec^{-1} x = \frac {1}{x\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}\\
\frac {d}{dx} \sec^{-1} ax = \frac {1}{x\sqrt{a^2x^2-1}}\\
\frac {d}{dx} \frac 1a \sec^{-1} \frac {x}{a} = \frac {1}{x\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}\\
\frac {d}{dx} \tan^{-1} x = \frac {1}{x^2 + 1}$

etc.

So, rather than using the substitution $x = \frac 34 \sec t$ and simplifying. We would try to make the integral into a constant times something we can find on a table of known derivatives.

$\int \frac {1}{x\sqrt{16x^2 - 9}}\ dx\\
 \int \frac {1}{3x\sqrt{(\frac 43x)^2 - 1}}\ dx$

Which is on our table.

This is far less versitile than the substitution

$x = \frac 34 \sec t\\
dx = \frac 34 \sec t\tan t \ dt$

$\int \frac { \frac 34 \sec t\tan t \ dt}{\frac 34\sec t\sqrt {9\tan^2 t}} \ dt\\
\frac 13 \int \ dt\\
\frac 13 t + C$

and reverse the substitution.

$t = \sec^{-1} \frac 43x\\
\frac 13 \sec^{-1} \frac 43x + C$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{16 x^2-9}} d x = & \frac{1}{16} \int \frac{1}{x^2}  d\left(\sqrt{16 x^2-9}\right) \\
= & \int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{16 x^2-9}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{16 x^2-9}\right)^2+9} \\
= & \frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{16 x^2-9}}{3}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

WLOG, let us assume that $x > 3/4$. I would recommend you to notice that
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{16x^{2} - 9}} & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}\sqrt{16 - 9x^{-2}}}\\\\
& = -\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(1/x)}{\sqrt{16 - 9x^{-2}}}\\\\
& = -\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{16 - 9u^{2}}}
\end{align*}
Which is (almost) a standard integral.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score -1):

[This answer is the same as the answer with secant inverse, since $\arcsecx + \arccosecx = \pi/2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIAwM.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.